# Paho Libraray For Objective C (iOS) Publish/Subscribe callbacks

Tags: ios, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho Library for MQTT Connectivity for Objective C language.
I am successfully able to connect, publish and subscribe.
But the problem is that I am not getting where will I get callbacks when a successful Publish/Subscribe occurs.
I can not get any documentation for the same.

Please help is any one has any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `MQTTSessionDelegate` to your controller interface

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MQTTSessionDelegate>
```

When creating a MQTT session, set your controller as delegate

```
session = [[MQTTSession alloc] init];
session.transport = transport;

session.delegate=self;
```

Implement then in your controller the callback methods you need.

All callbacks methods are [viewable in MQTTSession.h](https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework/blob/master/MQTTClient/MQTTClient/MQTTSession.h)

Read more on [MQTT Github page](https://github.com/ckrey/MQTT-Client-Framework)